# PIL - Unable to change the transparency level for JPEG image

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create an image and fill it with a semi-transparent black colour:

```
  from PIL import Image
  from PIL import ImageFont
  from PIL import ImageDraw
  from PIL import ImageEnhance


  fnt = create_font()

  # my background rectangle
  img1 = Image.new("RGBA", 100, 100, color=(0, 0, 0, 230)) #RGBA
  dr1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img1)
  dr1.text((5, 5), "some text", font=fnt)

  # my source image
  my_img.paste(dr1, (10, 10))
  my_img.save(out_file, "JPEG")
```

But it ignores the "230" being the transparency level. If I change it to "0" or any other number, the transparency level of "dr1" rectangle
stays the same -- it's completely black.

**update:**

I have a source in jpeg `my_img`. I want to put a semi-transparent rectangle on its part `img1` with a text. How can I do that? How can I get `img1` more transparent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the image file as a `JPEG`.

JPEGs do not support transparency. In order for your image to have transparency, you must save as a format that supports transparency in the image, such as a `PNG`.

Comment: so if my source image is jpeg and I want to put a semi-transparent rectangle on it, how should I change my code?

Comment: should I create a png rectangle? and put it on on a jpeg image? and save all that in jpeg?

Comment: The final line, `my_img.save(out_file, "JPEG")`, should be saved as a `PNG`, not `JPEG`. In essence, the final saved file is the one that matters in this case.

Comment: when I save it in jpeg, it's size if about 0.5 Mb, whereas in png it's a few Mb. is there any way to fix that?

Comment: `PNG` is a lossless format, whereas JPEG is lossy. The biggest downfall of the `PNG` format is how large the output files are, so no, there is no way around that sadly. You might be able to try and find another format that `PIL` supports, that also supports transparency. Did this solve your issue though?

Comment: not yet how about saving it in png and then converting to jpeg?

Comment: You can save to `PNG`, then convert to `JPEG`, but after that conversion, you will lose your transparency.

Comment: it's a single picture and merged, why?

Comment: Because you are converting the entire merged file into a JPEG. JPEG supports colors but no transparency. When you convert the file into a JPEG, all of its transparency information would be discarded.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, JPEG doesn't support transparency, so if you want an image file with transparency you'll need to use a different format, eg PNG.

I don't know where that `create_font` function is defined; there isn't a function of that name in my PIL ImageFont (I'm using PIL.PILLOW_VERSION == '3.3.0' on Python 3.6 on 32 bit Linux).

Also, that paste operation won't work, but you don't need it.

Here's a modified version of your code.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

img1 = Image.new("RGBA", (100, 100), color=(0, 0, 0, 64))
dr1 = ImageDraw.Draw(img1)
fnt = ImageFont.load_default()
dr1.text((5, 5), "some text", font=fnt, fill=(255, 255, 0, 128))

#img1.show()
img1.save('test.png')
```

And here's the PNG file it creates:

[image: transparent yellow text on a transparent black background]

---

Here's some code for your updated question.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFont, ImageDraw

img1 = Image.open('hueblock.jpg').convert("RGBA")

overlay = Image.new("RGBA", (100, 100), color=(0, 0, 0, 63))
dr1 = ImageDraw.Draw(overlay)
fnt = ImageFont.load_default()
dr1.text((5, 5), "some text", font=fnt, fill=(255, 255, 255, 160))

img1.paste(overlay, (64, 64), overlay)
img1.show()
img1.save('test.jpg')
```

Here are **hueblock.jpg** and **test.jpg**

[image: hueblock.jpg] [image: hueblock with transparent text]

---

Note the arguments to the paste call:

```
img1.paste(overlay, (64, 64), overlay)
```

The final argument is an image mask. By supplying an RGBA image as the mask arg its alpha channel is used as the mask, as mentioned in [the Pillow docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.paste)

> [...] If a mask is given, this method updates only the regions
>   indicated by the mask. You can use either “1”, “L” or “RGBA” images
>   (in the latter case, the alpha band is used as mask). Where the mask
>   is 255, the given image is copied as is. Where the mask is 0, the
>   current value is preserved. Intermediate values will mix the two
>   images together, including their alpha channels if they have them.

Comment: `I don't know where that create_font function is defined;` -- why don't you ask?

Comment: @ako25 Please feel free to add that info to your question. ;)